# Recuperar el valor de retorno de un procedimiento almacenado en VBA

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access

Tengo el siguiente codigo en vba, donde se ejecuta un procedimiento almacenado en SQL SERVER:

```
Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
Dim Sql As String
Dim Id As Integer = 10

Sql = "Declare @CadenaRetorno varchar(max)"
Sql = Sql & vbCrLf & "EXECUTE [CalcularDatos] @Id='" & Id & "', @StrRetorno = @CadenaRetorno OUTPUT;"

cmd.ActiveConnection = "DATABASE=Master"
cmd.CommandTimeout = 0
cmd.CommandText = Sql
cmd.Execute
```

¿Cómo puedo obtener el valor de retorno del parametro OUTPUT del procedimiento y almacenarlo en una variable en VBA?

Answer (score 2):

Para recuperar el valor de un parámetro, debes utilizar un comando de tipo `adCmdStoredProc`, y agregarle los parámetros *a mano*.

Al definir un parámetro de salida puedes consultar su propiedad `Value` después de la ejecución del procedimiento almacenado.

Algo en la línea de:

```vba
Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
Dim Id As Integer = 10

cmd.ActiveConnection = "DATABASE=Master"
cmd.CommandTimeout = 0
cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
cmd.CommandText = "[CalcularDatos]"

cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@Id", adinteger, adparamInput, , Id)
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@StrRetorno", adVarChar, adParamOutput, 8000)

cmd.Execute
MsgBox "Valor obtenido: " & cmd.Parameters("@StrRetorno").Value
```